# I want to write a single line in file using shell script linux

Tags: linux, shell, file-io

I have some input let say "somespacehere .file somemorespace    "sample.cpp"".
The above line I want to write in a file using shell script.
How should I write a shell script?
Please help me.
Thanks.

I write a code as

```
#!/bin/bash
filename= "./xyz.txt"
file = open(filename,'w')
echo "  .file    \"sample.cpp\"" > file
file .close()
```

It is giving me the error as

Syntax error: "(" unexpected
at last line.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Are you looking to concatenate multiple commands into a single line? Are you looking to pass the output of one command as an argument to another?

Comment: I just want to write  string startshere  somespace  .file somemorespace   "sample.cpp" stringendshere into a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start with a shebang and an echo the line you want to a file? For example,

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="./xyz.txt"
echo "  .file    \"sample.cpp\"" > $filename
```

Comment: You'll want to escape those inner quotes.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, appreciated your feedback and I've updated the answer with escaping inner quote.